# Simple animation div to div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to move a div to another div only using javascript?

I am very bad at javascript/jquery and I just wanted to do a simple animation of products to move into a shopping cart.

If it is not possible (or very hard) to do with javascript only I am also willing to do it with jquery.

I also wanted to eventually add an effect of fade out + shrink.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: it's actually possible to do some simple animations (fadeout, shrink) purely with css/html o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the div1 is absolutely positioned, you could do something like this:

```
var new_position = $(".div2").offset();
$(".div1").animate(new_position, 5000); // where 5000 is time in mil
```

fading out and shrinking can be done using the animate property as well

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to move a div to another div only using javascript?

Yes

> I am very bad at javascript/jquery and I just wanted to do a simple animation of products to move into a shopping cart.
>
> If it is not possible (or very hard) to do with javascript only I am also willing to do it with jquery.

Here's [MDN for JS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), and [jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/). You can start off from there

> I also wanted to eventually add an effect of fade out + shrink.

You can play around with jQueryUI for effects, especially [`.hide()`](http://jqueryui.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
div1.onclick = function()
{
div1.style.left = "12px" //or somewhere within div2
div1.style.top = "12px" //or somewhere within div2
}
</script>
```